# How to pass two textfield entries to another ViewController with using segue

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I want my user to go to the TableViewController once they enter their "id" and "password" but when we use prepare and performsegue methods we just send one variable.

```
@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailSegue", sender: emailTextField.text)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "passwordSegue", sender: passwordTextField.text)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let guest = segue.destination as! ExpenseTableViewController

    guest.incoming.append(sender as! String)
}
```

As you can see here I want to perform two different segues and I have also created two segues on the storyboard from ViewController to tableview controller named as "emailSegue" and "passwordSegue", but in the prepare function I can only prepare for the one of them which is the "emailSegue" when I run the code, it does compile and I can append email to the array but not my password.

So I wonder how I can get them both to be sent? Is there a way to prepare for 2 different segues? Could not find an example of it on anywhere else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only segue once at a time.  You can't have two View Controllers presented at the same time.

Comment: you can `segue` to one view Controller, you can also send data to different view Controllers before you segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only perform **one** segue, but you can send **multiple** parameters.

Just pass an array rather than a single string:

```
@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: Any) {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailSegue", 
                sender: [emailTextField.text!, passwordTextField.text!])
}
```

---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "emailSegue" {
       let guest = segue.destination as! ExpenseTableViewController
       guest.incoming.append(contentsOf: sender as! [String])
    }
}
```

---

PS: Rather than forced unwrapping the `text` properties you should validate them:

```
@IBAction func logIn(_ sender: Any) {
   guard let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty,
         let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty else {
      // show an alert
      return 
   }
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "emailSegue", sender: [email, password])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only perform one segue at a time, so call `performSegue` only once when you want the transition to happen and set the two variables in `prepareForSegue` for the destination view controller. It's best to check what type of segue should be prepared by checking `segue.identifier` property.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved my problem, appreciated that!

Comment: That's great to hear! :)